# Docker-compose blkio: device_write_iops not working for AWS/EBS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, devops

I am trying to limit iops on a particular container in my docker-compose stack. To do this I am using the following config:

```
blkio_config:
  device_write_iops:
    - path: "/dev/xvda1"
      rate: 20
  device_read_iops:
    - path: "/dev/xvda1"
      rate: 20
```

I cannot provide the rest of the file for security reasons however it is isolated to this statement. I confirmed that this is the correct path for my ebs volume using the `df -h` command.

When I then run `docker-compose up -d` I get the following error:

```
Recreating e1c25c41b612_drone ... error

ERROR: for e1c25c41b612_drone  Cannot start service drone: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"process_linux.go:396: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \\\"failed to write 202:1 20 to blkio.throttle.read_iops_device: write /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/docker/a674e86d50111afa576d5fd4e16a131070c100b7db3ac22f95986904a47ae82a/blkio.throttle.read_iops_device: invalid argument\\\"\"": unknown

ERROR: for drone  Cannot start service drone: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"process_linux.go:396: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \\\"failed to write 202:1 20 to blkio.throttle.read_iops_device: write /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/docker/a674e86d50111afa576d5fd4e16a131070c100b7db3ac22f95986904a47ae82a/blkio.throttle.read_iops_device: invalid argument\\\"\"": unknown
```

The iops limit on my EBS instance is 120 and so I tested using a variety of different values to no avail.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: I see the files mentioned in the error, perhaps I could manually add the config, but I do not know what it is and I would like it contained within docker-compose.